# Verify search results using boolean value in if else

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I have to automate the functionality of search.There are 2 possible out comes. one is result is generated the other is results not found. if there are matching results to search criteria a new div element is visible with results. If there are no results results not found message will display in a separate div element. Only one div element is visible at a time. so I have verified the search results as below.

```
Boolean resultPresent = driver
            .findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-once='ajax-pager']/div[@class='view-content row']")).isDisplayed();

    if (resultPresent == true) {
        Assert.assertTrue(resultPresent);
        
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-taeser-view']")).isDisplayed());
    } else {

        System.out.print("no products");

        List<WebElement> emptyMsg = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='view-empty']/p"));

        Assert.assertTrue(emptyMsg.get(0).isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertEquals(emptyMsg.get(0).getText(), "Couldn’t find any devices");

        Assert.assertTrue(emptyMsg.get(1).isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertEquals(emptyMsg.get(1).getText(),
                "It seems we don’t have any devices with the filters you have selected at the moment. Try using a different set of filters");
    }
```

What I have done is, check the visibility of search results and used that to validate results or the results not found value.

But when there are no results to I'm getting `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@data-once='ajax-pager']/div[@class='view-content row']"}`

Below is the html code for results

```
    <div class="views-element-container container-fluid"><div class="product-catalog-view view view-phone-catalog view-id-phone_catalog view-display-id-block_phone_catalog js-view-dom-id-285cae00df842a0b6be483f000119c9f43711985a6974010b9f451e16dd8c6f5" data-once="ajax-pager">
  
    
        <div class="view-filters">
      
<form class="views-exposed-form" data-drupal-selector="views-exposed-form-phone-catalog-block-phone-catalog" action="/shop/phones" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-phone-catalog-block-phone-catalog" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-once="exposed-form">
    <details class="filter-block js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" data-drupal-selector="edit-filter-block" aria-describedby="edit-filter-block--description" id="edit-filter-block" open="open">
  <summary role="button" aria-controls="edit-filter-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-pressed="true" style="display: none;">FILTER<span class="show"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
    <span class="hide"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></span>
    <span class="summary"></span>
  </summary>
  <div class="form-row">
    



  <fieldset class="js-form-item js-form-type-cshs form-type-cshs js-form-item-brand form-item-brand mb-3">
          <label for="edit-brand--3gXefRvFb2g">Brand/Family</label>
                    <div class="shop-cshs-field">
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-brand" class="simpler-select-root form-element form-element--type-select form-select" id="edit-brand--3gXefRvFb2g" name="brand" style="display: none;">
                  <option value="All" data-parent="" selected="selected">
          All
        </option>
                        <option value="1001" data-parent="">
          Apple
        </option>
                        <option value="1005" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 10
        </option>
                        <option value="1004" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 11
        </option>
                        <option value="1003" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 12
        </option>
                        <option value="1002" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 13
        </option>
                        <option value="1192" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 14
        </option>
                        <option value="1134" data-parent="">
          Phone ABC
        </option>
                        <option value="1193" data-parent="">
          Phone DEF
        </option>
                        <option value="1194" data-parent="1193">
          A
        </option>
                        <option value="997" data-parent="">
          Samsung
        </option>
                        <option value="998" data-parent="997">
          A Series
        </option>
                        <option value="1000" data-parent="997">
          Note Series
        </option>
                        <option value="999" data-parent="997">
          S Series
        </option>
                        <option value="1006" data-parent="">
          Huawei
        </option>
                        <option value="1007" data-parent="">
          Oppo
        </option>
                        <option value="1008" data-parent="1007">
          Series 60
        </option>
            </select><div class="select-wrapper select-wrapper--level-0" data-level="0"><select class="simpler-select form-element form-element--type-select form-select" id="edit-brand--3gXefRvFb2g--level-0"><option value="All">All</option><option value="1001" class="has-children">Apple</option><option value="1134">Phone ABC</option><option value="1193" class="has-children">Phone DEF</option><option value="997" class="has-children">Samsung</option><option value="1006">Huawei</option><option value="1007" class="has-children">Oppo</option></select></div>
</div>
                      </fieldset>




  <fieldset class="js-form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-price form-item-price mb-3">
          <label for="edit-price--fTIWV5xHUuQ">Price range</label>
                    
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-price" id="edit-price--fTIWV5xHUuQ" name="price" class="form-select"><option value="All" selected="selected">All</option><option value="1">Below Rs. 10,000</option><option value="2">Rs. 10,000 - 25,000</option><option value="3">Rs. 25,000 - 50,000</option><option value="4">Rs. 50,000 - 100,000</option><option value="5">Rs. 100,000 - 200,000</option><option value="6">Above Rs. 200,000</option></select>
                      </fieldset>




  <fieldset class="js-form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-cameras form-item-cameras mb-3">
          <label for="edit-cameras--hPq_KbJeRps">Number of Cameras</label>
                    
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-cameras" id="edit-cameras--hPq_KbJeRps" name="cameras" class="form-select"><option value="All">All</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4" selected="selected">More than 3</option></select>
                      </fieldset>
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-group container-fluid" id="edit-actions--RZeuRpm2i6s"><button class="btn btn-danger button js-form-submit form-submit" data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-phone-catalog-1v9fjqnbt6a" type="submit" id="edit-submit-phone-catalog--1V9FjqnbT6A" value="FILTER">FILTER</button>
</div>

  </div>
</details>
<script>
  function setFilterVisibility() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
      // Hide the toggle button and display the filters
      $(".filter-block").attr('open', true);
      $(".filter-block > summary").hide();
    } else {
              $(".filter-block").attr('open', true);
        $(".filter-block > summary").show();
          }
  }

  setFilterVisibility();

  $(window).on('orientationchange resize', setFilterVisibility);
</script>
</form>

    </div>
    
      <div class="view-content row">
          <div class="product-teaser views-row">
    
<article class="commerce-product--phones--teaser commerce-product--teaser">
      <div class="no-promotions-block"></div>
    <div class="product-taeser-view">
    <div class="product-taeser-block1">
      
      <div class="product--variation-field--variation_field_images__5 field field--name-field-images field--type-image field--label-hidden field--items">
              <div class="field--item">  <img loading="lazy" src="https://dialog-qa-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2022-03/Black%201.jpg?itok=hUs-qGRy" width="55" height="100" alt="Front view" typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-product-thumbnail">


</div>
          </div>
  
      <div class="product-taeser-block2">
        
            <div class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">iPhone 12</div>
      
        <div class="price-label">Price</div>
        
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_price__5 field field--name-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 3,000.00</div>
      
                  <span class="list-price"></span> <span class="discount-text">&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
    </div>
              
            <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-mini-specification field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field--item"><ul>
    <li>6.1 inch Super Retina XDR display</li>
    <li>5G mmWave and sub-6GHz&nbsp;5G mmWave and sub-6GHz&nbsp;5G mmWave and sub-6GHz&nbsp;5G mmWave and sub-6GHz</li>
    <li>5G mmWave and sub-6GHz</li>
</ul>
</div>
      
        <div class="buy-now-button">
      <a href="/product/5" class="commerce-product--catalog__hover-text">BUY NOW</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

  </div>
    <div class="product-teaser views-row">
    
<article class="commerce-product--phones--teaser commerce-product--teaser">
      <div class="promotions-block">
      <div class="promotions-text">
        
            <div class="field field--name-field-offer-tag-line field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">10% OFF</div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-taeser-view">
    <div class="product-taeser-block1">
      
      <div class="product--variation-field--variation_field_images__3 field field--name-field-images field--type-image field--label-hidden field--items">
              <div class="field--item">  <img loading="lazy" src="https://dialog-qa-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2022-04/Black%201_0.jpg?itok=VtCJKZVP" width="81" height="100" alt="Front view" typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-product-thumbnail">


</div>
          </div>
  
      <div class="product-taeser-block2">
        
            <div class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">Samsung Galaxy S21</div>
      
        <div class="price-label">Price</div>
        
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_price__3 field field--name-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 92,500.00</div>
      
                  <span class="list-price"></span> <span class="discount-text">&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
    </div>
              
            <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-mini-specification field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field--item"><ul>
    <li>256GB US Version Smartphone</li>
    <li>Pro-Grade Camera 8K Video 64MP High Res</li>
    <li>Phantom Black</li>
</ul>
</div>
      
        <div class="buy-now-button">
      <a href="/product/3" class="commerce-product--catalog__hover-text">BUY NOW</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

  </div>
    <div class="product-teaser views-row">
    
<article class="commerce-product--phones--teaser commerce-product--teaser">
      <div class="promotions-block">
      <div class="promotions-text">
        
            <div class="field field--name-field-offer-tag-line field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">20%  off</div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-taeser-view">
    <div class="product-taeser-block1">
      
      <div class="product--variation-field--variation_field_images__4 field field--name-field-images field--type-image field--label-hidden field--items">
              <div class="field--item">  <img loading="lazy" src="https://dialog-qa-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2022-04/Black%201.jpg?itok=8JDWTIiJ" width="81" height="100" alt="Front" typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-product-thumbnail">


</div>
          </div>
  
      <div class="product-taeser-block2">
        
            <div class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item">Samsung Galaxy S21 - V3</div>
      
        <div class="price-label">Price</div>
        
            <div class="product--variation-field--variation_price__4 field field--name-price field--type-commerce-price field--label-hidden field--item">Rs. 75,000.00</div>
      
                  <span class="list-price"></span> <span class="discount-text">&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
    </div>
              
            <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-mini-specification field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field--item"><ul>
    <li>256GB US Version Smartphone</li>
    <li>Pro-Grade Camera 8K Video 64MP High Res</li>
    <li>Phantom Black</li>
</ul>
</div>
      
        <div class="buy-now-button">
      <a href="/product/4" class="commerce-product--catalog__hover-text">BUY NOW</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

  </div>

    </div>
  
      
          </div>
</div>
```

Below is the html code for results not found

```
    <div class="views-element-container container-fluid"><div class="product-catalog-view view view-phone-catalog view-id-phone_catalog view-display-id-block_phone_catalog js-view-dom-id-b86f8e377d10a5f1f0bb168655a850991721dd19d827dd1aee1e8d6f55ad79d0" data-once="ajax-pager">
  
    
        <div class="view-filters">
      
<form class="views-exposed-form" data-drupal-selector="views-exposed-form-phone-catalog-block-phone-catalog" action="/shop/phones" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-phone-catalog-block-phone-catalog" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-once="exposed-form">
    <details class="filter-block js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" data-drupal-selector="edit-filter-block" aria-describedby="edit-filter-block--description" id="edit-filter-block" open="open">
  <summary role="button" aria-controls="edit-filter-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-pressed="true" style="display: none;">FILTER<span class="show"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
    <span class="hide"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></span>
    <span class="summary"></span>
  </summary>
  <div class="form-row">
    



  <fieldset class="js-form-item js-form-type-cshs form-type-cshs js-form-item-brand form-item-brand mb-3">
          <label for="edit-brand--2YqqeNkJSSo">Brand/Family</label>
                    <div class="shop-cshs-field">
  <select data-drupal-selector="edit-brand" class="simpler-select-root form-element form-element--type-select form-select" id="edit-brand--2YqqeNkJSSo" name="brand" style="display: none;">
                  <option value="All" data-parent="" selected="selected">
          All
        </option>
                        <option value="1001" data-parent="">
          Apple
        </option>
                        <option value="1005" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 10
        </option>
                        <option value="1004" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 11
        </option>
                        <option value="1003" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 12
        </option>
                        <option value="1002" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 13
        </option>
                        <option value="1192" data-parent="1001">
          iPhone 14
        </option>
                        <option value="1134" data-parent="">
          Phone ABC
        </option>
                        <option value="1193" data-parent="">
          Phone DEF
        </option>
                        <option value="1194" data-parent="1193">
          A
        </option>
                        <option value="997" data-parent="">
          Samsung
        </option>
                        <option value="998" data-parent="997">
          A Series
        </option>
                        <option value="1000" data-parent="997">
          Note Series
        </option>
                        <option value="999" data-parent="997">
          S Series
        </option>
                        <option value="1006" data-parent="">
          Huawei
        </option>
                        <option value="1007" data-parent="">
          Oppo
        </option>
                        <option value="1008" data-parent="1007">
          Series 60
        </option>
            </select><div class="select-wrapper select-wrapper--level-0" data-level="0"><select class="simpler-select form-element form-element--type-select form-select" id="edit-brand--2YqqeNkJSSo--level-0"><option value="All">All</option><option value="1001" class="has-children">Apple</option><option value="1134">Phone ABC</option><option value="1193" class="has-children">Phone DEF</option><option value="997" class="has-children">Samsung</option><option value="1006">Huawei</option><option value="1007" class="has-children">Oppo</option></select></div>
</div>
                      </fieldset>




  <fieldset class="js-form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-price form-item-price mb-3">
          <label for="edit-price--mxwdlAvPjPU">Price range</label>
                    
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-price" id="edit-price--mxwdlAvPjPU" name="price" class="form-select"><option value="All">All</option><option value="1">Below Rs. 10,000</option><option value="2">Rs. 10,000 - 25,000</option><option value="3" selected="selected">Rs. 25,000 - 50,000</option><option value="4">Rs. 50,000 - 100,000</option><option value="5">Rs. 100,000 - 200,000</option><option value="6">Above Rs. 200,000</option></select>
                      </fieldset>




  <fieldset class="js-form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-cameras form-item-cameras mb-3">
          <label for="edit-cameras--V80k4YksURU">Number of Cameras</label>
                    
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-cameras" id="edit-cameras--V80k4YksURU" name="cameras" class="form-select"><option value="All">All</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3" selected="selected">3</option><option value="4">More than 3</option></select>
                      </fieldset>
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-group container-fluid" id="edit-actions--kg_yrb-6QN0"><button class="btn btn-danger button js-form-submit form-submit" data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-phone-catalog-zwvv2azewoo" type="submit" id="edit-submit-phone-catalog--ZWVV2AZeWOo" value="FILTER">FILTER</button>
</div>

  </div>
</details>
<script>
  function setFilterVisibility() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
      // Hide the toggle button and display the filters
      $(".filter-block").attr('open', true);
      $(".filter-block > summary").hide();
    } else {
              $(".filter-block").attr('open', true);
        $(".filter-block > summary").show();
          }
  }

  setFilterVisibility();

  $(window).on('orientationchange resize', setFilterVisibility);
</script>
</form>

    </div>
    
      <div class="view-empty">
      <br>
<img src="https://dialog-dev-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/2022-05/no_results.png" width="250px" class="align-center">
<br>
<p class="text-center"><strong class="align-center">Couldn’t find any devices</strong></p>
<p class="text-center">It seems we don’t have any devices with the filters you have selected at the moment. Try using a different set of filters</p>
    </div>    
          </div>
</div>
```

these products value can be changed and configured any time. I need to execute either one of scenarios any time. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NoSuchElementException is in this case correct because the no Results case is not wrapped into an div with the data-once ajax-pager property, which will always result in an Exception.

I might be missing something here, but is there a reason why you do not just do a `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('.buy-now-button')).length > 0` ?

As far as I see the Button gets only displayed for search results, and findElements, other than findElement, does not throw an excepton if no elements are present.